# Mocking WLResponse throws ClassNotFoundException for HttpResponse

Tags: android, unit-testing, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm in the process of writing unit tests for an Android project that uses MFP 7.1 and I'm attempting to test some functionality which takes an `WLResponse` object as an input. I'd like to mock this object as the only thing I need from it is the `JSONObject` that gets returned by calling its `getResponseJSON` method.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
    Mockito.when(jsonObject.toString()).thenReturn(person.toString());

    WLResponse wlResponse = Mockito.mock(WLResponse.class);
    Mockito.when(wlResponse.getResponseJSON()).thenReturn(jsonObject);
```

The issue is that when I call `Mockito.mock(WLResponse.class)` I get the following exception thrown at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpResponse
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.setConstructorsAccessible(ClassImposterizer.java:75)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:70)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
at com.ibm.mil.cafejava.GsonConverterTest.before(GsonConverterTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpResponse
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 38 more
```

I'm using the MFP 7.1 SDK that is provided through jcenter, specifically:

```
compile 'com.ibm.mobile.foundation:ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation:7.1.0'
```

From what I can infer, `WLResponse` has a constructor which takes an `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` object as an argument. But looking at the dependencies that MFP uses, it relies on the [android-async-http](https://github.com/https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/android-async-http) library, which in turn relies on the [httpclient-android](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android) library. It is this second library which has the `HttpResponse` class that the first one uses, but the package it's located in is `cz/msebera/android/httpclient/` and not `org/apache/http/`. Perhaps this could be the source of the error, since the `WLResponse` constructor is expecting `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` instead, preventing Mockito from being able to mock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that [Android 6.0  removes support for the Apache HTTP client](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). Assuming your `compileSdkVersion` is 23, try adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```